# Login popup box not working in Firefox but is OK in Chrome

Tags: authentication, popup

I have read the advice on posting a question that should be as precise as possible and used the advanced search facility so I hope my question has not been covered previously.

**NOTE:** I am not a programmer and can only just about find my way around code (in my site`s cpanel).

My site`s login popup box does not work in Firefox - although it did so for 3 years prior, up until a few weeks ago, so maybe there is an issue with a recent FF update). It does however work OK in Chrome.

Hovering over the login/register text shows the `alt` tag "Click to show popup login form" but nothing happens when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a URL for others to see what you're referring to?

Firefox was just updated to version 18 I believe. I would try and downgrade to 17 just to confirm that it's an issue with FF. If it is I'd open an issue with mozilla (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/). Also search there for your issue.